# Convert PDF documents to TIFF using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

Using iTextSharp, I want to convert PDF documents into Tiff. Is there any example? Thanks for your time.

Comment: According to this solution it is achievable with iText7 :) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414913/itext7-creating-pdf-from-tiff-multipage-image-using-itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414913/itext7-creating-pdf-from-tiff-multipage-image-using-itext)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that with iTextSharp and [someone](http://old.nabble.com/iTextSharp-pdf-to-tiff-td17280631.html) agrees with me.
Take a look at [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/): with a little work you can achieve your goal.